# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shared')

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to use `PIXI.Loader()`. As docs say `Loader` was removed from pixi version 5 and I am using version 7.1.1. I am trying to use `PIXI.Loader.shared`;

Console returns:

```
Symbols.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shared')
```

Here is my code:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

export default class Symbols {
    constructor(onAssetsLoaded) {
        this.symbolHeight = 40;
        this.symbolSpacing = 120;
        this.symbols = [];
        this.symbolPaths = [];
        this.rngMap = {};

        this.loader = PIXI.Loader.shared;
        this.loadAssets();
        this.loader.once('complete', onAssetsLoaded);
        this.loader.load();
    }

    loadAssets() {
        this.loader.add('symbols', 'assets/symbol_0_base.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use PIXI 7 you should migrate from Loader to Assets as the [migration guide](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v7-Migration-Guide#-replaces-loader-with-assets) indicates.

Here is the working code for your use case. Keep in mind that I am using `pixijs` and not `pixi.js` as a dependency:

```js
import * as PIXI from 'pixijs';

export default class Symbols {
    constructor(onAssetsLoaded) {
        this.symbolHeight = 40;
        this.symbolSpacing = 120;
        this.symbols = [];
        this.symbolPaths = [];
        this.rngMap = {};

        this.loader = PIXI.Assets;
        this.loadAssets().then(onAssetsLoaded);
    }

    loadAssets() {
        this.loader.add('symbols', 'assets/symbol_0_base.png');

        return this.loader.load('symbols');
    }
}
```

More documentation about the new Assets module can be found [here](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Assets.html).